# HTTP requests in CSS obtained via HTTPS

Tags: html, css, http, ssl, https

What happens if a user is connected to my website via HTTPS but my CSS contains absolute path references to pictures via HTTP?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others already have written, the browser shows a warning about the partly unsecure page.

The reason for this behaviour is, that having a session cookie, this cookie will be sent along with this unsecure HTTP requests (even for pictures). So if you are not prevent this explicitely, it would be possible to hijack the session, what makes the security of your site worthless.

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely get a warning from your browser that certain page elements are going to be transferred over a non-secure connection, thereby compromising the overall security of your page. Other than that, nothing *bad* will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Then the browser fetches the images over HTTP … and may warn the user that the page is partially insecure.